# Date Calculation Between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, math, date

I need some help doing a date calculation.

I have something that Expires every `X` number of days away from its `Create Date`

So, if the `Create Date` was `4/22` and the Expiration days were set to `10` it would expire

`5/2, 5/12, 5/22, 6/1` etc...

I need to be able to tell people when their item is going to expire within 5 days

So for 5/2, I need to add this item to a count if the current date is between 4/27 and 5/2.

This is in SQL.

All we have are the `RunDate`, the `CreateDate` and the `ExpirationDays`

I've done the math calc to roughly get the Expiration date, but if it gets a remainder it's not helpful, and I don't want to skew anyone's answer by posting what I think it should be. I've tried quite a few ways and am getting a little desperate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**

I did the math for this and it looks like this

`CreateDate + (((RunDate - CreateDate)/ExpireDays)*ExpireDays)) Between Rundate-1 and Rundate +5`

But this gives me arithmetic overflow in SQL, so I'm not sure what to do...

Comment: The tags `date`, `calculation`, and `expiration` have `20`,`5`, and `0` followers respectively. Much more useful to tag the RDBMS as date functions differ.

Answer (score 0):

In MySql you could do something

```
(ExpirationDays - (DATEDIFF(NOW(), CreateDate) % ExpirationDays)) > 5;
```

**EDIT**

For SQL Server you would do it a little different:

```
@expiringDays - (DATEDIFF(dd, ml.CreateDate, @date) % @expiringDays) > 5;
```

Comment: So I've done this with mod and it keeps biting me, but i've never tried it with <, always `BETWEEN`

Comment: How has it been giving you problems?

Comment: So, here's the scenario that gave me trouble:

`DATEDIFF(dd, ml.CreateDate, @date) % @expiringDays`

where `CreateDate = 4/7, @date = 5/10, ExpireDays = 30`

DateDiff = 33 % 30 = 3 which is between 0 and 5 but it shouldn't expire again until 6/6 so between 6/1 and 6/6

So I tried `ExpireDays - (DATEDIFF(dd, ml.CreateDate, @date) % @expiringDays)`

And then when ExpireDays = 10 it computes to 4 and when it's 11 it computes to 6.

I'm getting something twisted here, but i'm not sure what...

Comment: Oh yeah I had it backwards too, what about if we use > instead of <?

Comment: Hmm.. I'll give it a shot. I think the calc I'm doing is wrong because when you up the Expire days for the mod the left side of the subtraction goes up too, that's why increasing ExpireDays by 1 goes up 2 days...

Comment: Try it without any subtraction just `DATEDIFF(dd, ml.CreateDate, @date) % @expiringDays > 5`

Comment: I did, same reversed results.

Comment: I edited the original post, maybe that will help us figure this out. I have to run to a church band practice now, but I'll be back online in a while. I hope you're still here when I get back. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: What about @expiringDays - (DATEDIFF(dd, ml.CreateDate, @date) % @expiringDays) > 5

Answer (score 0):

```
With Expirations As
    (
    Select Cast('2011-04-22' As datetime) As CreateDate, 10 As ExpirationDays
    Union All
    Select DateAdd( d, ExpirationDays, CreateDate ), ExpirationDays
    From Expirations
    Where CreateDate <= DateAdd(d,10,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) --(arbitary end date)
    )
Select *
From Expirations
Where CreateDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    And CreateDate <= DateAdd(d,5,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

---

Using similar logic to the math you used in your updated post:

```
With Expirations As
    (
    Select Cast('2011-04-22' As datetime) As CreateDate, 10 As ExpirationDays
    Union All
    Select DateAdd( d, ExpirationDays, CreateDate ), ExpirationDays
    From Expirations
    Where CreateDate <= DateAdd(d,10,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) --(arbitary end date)
    )
Select *
From Expirations
Where CreateDate >= DateAdd(d, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    And CreateDate <= DateAdd(d, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```